# I have a list of numbers. I have to make the sum of the digits that are repeated using recursive functions

Tags: recursion, f#

This is my code and I don't understand why I can't do the sum. For example I have this list [1;1;2;2;2;2;3;3;4;3;3;3] in input and in out I need [2;8;6;4;9]. Can anyone help me with my problem ? Thank you.

```
 let rec compress l = 
    match l with
    [] -> []
    | [x] -> [x]
    | x::y::xs when x<>y -> compress(xs)
    | x::y::xs when x=y ->  (x+y)::compress(y::xs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution, using recursion:

```
let compress l =
    let rec loop last acc l = 
        match (l, last) with
        | [], None   -> []
        | [], Some _ -> [acc]
        | x::xs, None              -> loop (Some x) acc (x::xs)
        | x::xs, Some n when x = n -> loop last (n+acc) xs
        | x::xs, _                 -> acc :: loop (Some x) x xs
    loop None 0 l
```

It uses an addition parameter `acc` which accumulates the result and `last` which represents the previous element.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possible solution:

```
let compress l =
    if List.isEmpty l then []
    else
        let rec loop (last, acc) xs =
            let h = List.head acc
            match xs with
            | [] -> (last, acc)
            | y::ys when y = last -> loop (y, (y + h)::List.tail acc) ys
            | y::ys -> loop (y, y::acc) ys

        let h = List.head l
        List.tail l
        |> loop (h, [h]) 
        |> (snd >> List.rev)

compress l
val it : int list = [2; 8; 6; 4; 9]
```

Notice that the loop function is tail recursive.